# NULL Checking of boost::scoped_ptr

Tags: c++, boost

I'm new to boost framework and I'm not sure how can I check if the object in scoped_ptr is null.

```
boost::scoped_ptr<CFoo> cFoo(new CFoo);

if(NULL != cFoo)
{
    //todo
}
```

Comment: When nine hundred years old you reach, look as good, you will not, hmmm? (c) Yoda

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do

```
if(cFoo.get() != 0 ) //what you are trying to do
```

or just

```
if(cFoo) // as K-Ballo explains.
```

as explained at [`boost::scoped_ptr`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/smart_ptr/scoped_ptr.htm#conversions)

> **conversions**
>
> `operator unspecified-bool-type () const; // never throws`
> Returns an unspecified value that, when used in boolean contexts, **is equivalent to get() != 0.**

Answer (score 5):

It should be enough to do:

```
if( cFoo )
{ ... }
```

`scoped_ptr` has a *safe* implicit conversion to *bool* that will evaluate to `true` when its not null.

Comment: Furthermore, `cFoo` will never be null in the posted snippet, since `new` will throw if the allocation fails.

Comment: @Praetorian: Unless you disable exceptions with `-fno-exceptions` :)

Answer (score 0):

When "`new CFoo`" failed, it would throw exception, so I think you don't need to check if cFoo is null.
If you `new(std::nothrow)`, `if (cFoo)` is needed.